# Does it make sense to do TDD if I don't spend much time debugging?

Tags: debugging, haskell, f#, tdd

I am trying to make a case for myself to use TDD and the usual punch line is that **if you do TDD you don't spend much time debugging.** I am programming in F# and find that I spend little time debugging and code usually works first time around.

So the question is does the TDD punch line works in other direction - if I don't debug much then I don't need tests? What is your experience of using TDD with F# or Haskell? Are there any good open source projects in F# or Haskell which use TDD? Does other benefits like preventing overengineering outweigh the costs?

Comment: `code usually works first time around` Are you _sure_ that you've covered all the functional edge cases? Or does it just "appear" to work on a first, _single_ execution run so you shrug your shoulders and shout "done!"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - you'd be surprised just how true that statement is in functional programming languages from the ML family (that's not to claim that edge cases ought not to be covered, but there are less cases to consider and the language does give you less opportunities to miss the cases that remain)

Comment: Voted to reopen: I don't believe this question is "not constructive". The unit testing experience in F# really is different than the general community. Moreover, you could set up scientific studies around this question (not sure if there are any, but the potential is there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You spend less time debugging F# programs because the type system and emphasis on immutable data structures and pure functions eliminates whole classes of invalid programs.

So the converse of the statement "if you do TDD you don't spend much time debugging" does hold to a certain degree but should be "if your programming language has features that require you to debug less, then that may imply that you require less unit tests". That is, unit tests are used to prove the correctness of your code, but some languages like F# have compilers which can prove a lot more about your code for "free" than, say, a dynamic language.

That being said, unit tests are still a very powerful tool in languages from the ML family like F# for proving the correctness of your code, but you are able to focus on the correctness of your functionality rather than the correctness of your use of the language.

All of my F# open source projects have rigorous suites of unit tests (and I think they're pretty good :) and they have given me an invaluable peace of mind and protected me several times against regression issues.

- [Unquote](http://code.google.com/p/unquote/source/browse/?r=456#svn/trunk/UnquoteTests)
- [FsEye](http://code.google.com/p/fseye/source/browse/?r=250#svn/trunk/Test.FsEye)
- [NL](http://code.google.com/p/nl-compiler/source/browse/?r=22075d086de1eaceda9bdd0469c3656786d033d7#hg/Test.NL)

Comment: Thank you very much for the links! I think the distinction correctness of language/correctness of functionality is a good framework to apply for comparison of ways TDD is used in different languages.

Answer (score 11):

When your code grows substantially, when there are multiple people working on it, when you want to make sure that changes don't break the code functionally and don't introduce performance regressions, when you want to make sure that the next version/release doesn't become incompatible with the previous one, when you want to make sure the code works on multiple versions and configurations of the OS, when the cost of a bug is significant and may result in serious financial or legal issues, etc etc, you need to have tests.

Answer (score 4):

The amount of time spent debugging is directly proportional to the complexity of your code.  TDD is a method to reduce the complexity of your code at design time and maintenance time, so if you're writing really simple code then the answer to your first question is no.

Your code works, you don't need to prove that it works and no one will ever change your code?  If that's true then you don't need tests.

For me functional programming is less error prone in both design and implementation so I find less value in TDD. (see first paragraph again)

Preventing over-engineering is a wonderful thing.  Most projects don't have it as a requirement though and it does take time.  Over-engineering is fun.  Anyone whom tells you otherwise is denying their inner engineer.

I'd argue that TDD is something you need to practice, before you can appreciate the value in it.  Writing function signatures for test cases is often enough for me to figure out any design issues I have.  I rarely fill out all my test code, because I also rarely have requirements that force me to go back and change my code.  Your mileage may vary depending on your needs.

Comment: +1 for "denying their inner engineer", and agree with your point on function signatures. Writing a test helps identify whether a particular signature is usable or painful, and with practice simply thinking through what tests you would write will be sufficient to find out issues. You can get similar insight without writing tests, using fsi - but at the end of a REPL session, the effort of converting code into a test is minimal so you might as well do it...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good post about what TDD is good for. It's a bit tongue-in-cheek, written sarcastically, but it demonstrates the value of testing first: [10 Reasons to Avoid Test Driven Development](http://www.softwareandi.com/2011/12/10-reasons-to-avoid-test-driven.html)